# PHP Error reporting not working

Tags: php, ini

I am unable to see error reporting with php 7.1.0 I have adjusted the ini file as directed, reset server mysql db and laptop nothing has changed. At this point I am lost as all the documents I have read confirm what I have done as the correct procedure??

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Error handling and logging ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; error_reporting is a bit-field.  Or each number up to get desired error
; reporting level
; E_ALL             - All errors and warnings
; E_ERROR           - fatal run-time errors
; E_WARNING         - run-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_PARSE           - compile-time parse errors
; E_NOTICE          - run-time notices (these are warnings which often result
;                     from a bug in your code, but it's possible that it was
;                     intentional (e.g., using an uninitialized variable and
;                     relying on the fact it's automatically initialized to an
;                     empty string)
; E_CORE_ERROR      - fatal errors that occur during PHP's initial startup
; E_CORE_WARNING    - warnings (non-fatal errors) that occur during PHP's
;                     initial startup
; E_COMPILE_ERROR   - fatal compile-time errors
; E_COMPILE_WARNING - compile-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_USER_ERROR      - user-generated error message
; E_USER_WARNING    - user-generated warning message
; E_USER_NOTICE     - user-generated notice message
;
; Examples:
;
;   - Show all errors, except for notices
;
;error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;
;   - Show only errors
;
;error_reporting = E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR
;
;   - Show all errors except for notices
;
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE

; Print out errors (as a part of the output).  For production web sites,
; you're strongly encouraged to turn this feature off, and use error logging
; instead (see below).  Keeping display_errors enabled on a production web site
; may reveal security information to end users, such as file paths on your Web
; server, your database schema or other information.
display_errors = On

; Even when display_errors is on, errors that occur during PHP's startup
; sequence are not displayed.  It's strongly recommended to keep
; display_startup_errors off, except for when debugging.
display_startup_errors = On

; Log errors into a log file (server-specific log, stderr, or error_log (below))
; As stated above, you're strongly advised to use error logging in place of
; error displaying on production web sites.
log_errors = On

; Set maximum length of log_errors. In error_log information about the source is
; added. The default is 1024 and 0 allows to not apply any maximum length at all.
log_errors_max_len = 1024

; Do not log repeated messages. Repeated errors must occur in same file on same
; line until ignore_repeated_source is set true.
ignore_repeated_errors = Off

; Ignore source of message when ignoring repeated messages. When this setting 
; is On you will not log errors with repeated messages from different files or
; sourcelines.
ignore_repeated_source = Off

; If this parameter is set to Off, then memory leaks will not be shown (on
; stdout or in the log). This has only effect in a debug compile, and if 
; error reporting includes E_WARNING in the allowed list
report_memleaks = On

; Store the last error/warning message in $php_errormsg (boolean).
track_errors = Off

; Disable the inclusion of HTML tags in error messages.
;html_errors = Off
```

Comment: Please do not abuse the code snippet tool. It should only be used for HTML/CSS/JavaScript questions

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct php.ini file on your system?

Comment: it could be that your application is overwriting reporting settings.

Comment: Its in MAMP/conf/php7.1.0

Comment: Have you tried using `ini_set()` to explicitly set the `display_errors` and `error_reporting` values inside a php script?

Comment: The localhost page isn’t working

localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Is the message I get when trying to access a php file with errors,  
I take it ini_set(display_errors, error_reporting) is the correct format?

Comment: `<?php
ini_set(display_errors, error_reporting);

echo $var= 'Alex'
    echo $var2 ='jimmy';
?>`